# Is there a way to remotely access my desktop and transfer files over the net to my S3?

Tags: file-transfer, remote-access

I have Win 7 Pro on my home desktop and a 4.1.1 OS Samsung S3 phone.  Is there a simple tool or something I can use to move around and transfer files directly from my desktop to the internal drive on my Android phone?  It would be good if I can stream videos to my phone too.  I have no knowledge of how to setup ports etc.  too so something simple.

Edit: I need to fransfer files that are like 700MB.  Desktop is in another city so wifi won't do.  And, I need to be able to set it up on the desktop by just a simple software download because someone else who is not conputer savvy has to setup the desktop while I do my Android.

Comment: You might want to take a look at our [most frequented file-transfer questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer). Plenty of good answers there :)

Answer (score 0):

To **transfer files** you can try [AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com/). But it is free only when the device are on the same wifi network. Access via mobile data is limited to 100 MB/Month.

For **video streaming**, you can try [Emit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.wpn.biokoda.android.emitfree&hl=en). The free version puts ads on your stream and you can stream to your phone even when not on the same network, but you'll need to mess a bit with ports.